# Android Kotlin Firebase how to update values in a record

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using `android studio 4.1.1` with Kotlin.  I'm learning myself how to do android programming with Kotlin.

I'm trying to update records in my database.

[image: my test firebase db]

In my code I'm doing this:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("weights").child(userId).child(weight.recordID.toString())
println("!!!!!!!!!!! Firebase reference: ${ref.toString()}")


ref.child("comments").setValue(weight.comments.toString())
ref.child("date").setValue(weight.date.toString())
ref.child("exerciseText").setValue(weight.exerciseText.toString())
...
```

My println shows: `...I/System.out: !!!!!!!!!!! Firebase reference: https://my-test-app-860ca-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/weights/oB3pzvhAr6foyhGZUuvFl4CECOw2/-MQTjdSW6TkJkDTzOKlv`

That looks correct - matches the record I'm testing: userID and recordID in Firebase web console.

The `setValue()` code matches what I see in the Firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write under `setValue()`.  I've verified via println's that the values I'm passing in are present

I'm not seeing the records update in my list in my app or in the Firebase web console.

Any ideas what I'm missing?  Is there some other command I have to run to actually commit the changes?

Comment: I think it is because the value is not being updated. You are writing the same value on database. Please check the new values are different from the old ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My values are different. I specifically enter different values.  Weird !  Note, some fields I did not change, but the ones I do change are not updating.

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the location? I recommend always catching errors with https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I believe so.  I have no problem creating records.  For writing, I do `ref.child(userId).child(recordID).setValue(weight).addOnCompleteListener{...` where `weight` is an object to my Weight class.  I create and update records in the same activity.

Comment: interesting. maybe my new values are empty.  `ref.child("comments").setValue(weight.comments.toString()).addOnCompleteListener{
    println("********* Weight Record add successfully ${weight.comments.toString()}")
}`   shows `********* Weight Record add successfully `  no value. hmmm!

Comment: That is unfortunately impossible for us to check, but should be easy to check for you. If that's indeed the problem, I'll probably vote to close as type/not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I have it.  I was doing something odd that was over-writing data in my class.  It took me a while to trace it out.   Cheers!